# POS extension that can be used inside a brick-and-mortar store

Tags: windows, magento, point-of-sale

Currently the best option I’ve seen is X-POS from Smartosc. But is there a good alternative?

I just need something I can use on my Windows 10 POS system that can keep track of inventory with Magento close to real time to prevent stock out orders.

Any recommended extensions that does not require a monthly fee, is a one time buy, and works with Windows?

I would estimate we would be having about 10,000-20,000 thousand unique SKUs.